An invalid form control with name="geschlecht'' is not focusable altough required is set to false
When the select menu is hidden this error occurs error message
altought I changed the required attribute to false in the code in javascript `  function update() {
if (rbttn_student.checked) {
        studiengang.style.display ="block";
        konfession.style.display="block";
        staatsangehörigkeit.style.display="block";
        geschlecht.style.display="block";
        konfession.setAttribute("required", "true");
        staatsangehörigkeit.setAttribute("required", "true");
        geschlecht_dropdown.setAttribute("required", "true");
        studiengang_dropdown.setAttribute("required","true" );
    } else if (rbttn_student.checked == false) 
    { 
        studiengang.style.display="none";
        konfession.style.display="none";
        staatsangehörigkeit.style.display="none"; 
        geschlecht.style.display="none";
        konfession.setAttribute("required", "false");
        staatsangehörigkeit.setAttribute("required", "false");
        geschlecht_dropdown.setAttribute("required", "false");
        studiengang_dropdown.setAttribute("required","false" );
    }
    //  Weitere Bedingungen für rbttn_dozent und rbttn_admin hier...


    if (rbttn_dozent.checked || rbttn_student.checked) 
    {
        
        konfession.style.display="block";
        staatsangehörigkeit.style.display="block";
    } 

    else if (rbttn_dozent.checked == true)
        {
                konfession.style.display="none";
                staatsangehörigkeit.style.display="none"; 
                konfession.setAttribute("required", "true");
                staatsangehörigkeit.setAttribute("required", "true");
                geschlecht_dropdown.setAttribute("required", "false");
                studiengang_dropdown.setAttribute("required","false" );
        
        }
    else if (rbttn_dozent.checked == false)
    {
            konfession.style.display="none";
            staatsangehörigkeit.style.display="none"; 
            konfession.setAttribute("required", "false");
            staatsangehörigkeit.setAttribute("required", "false");
    }

`
and this is how it looks like in html
<div id="geschlecht"> <select id="geschlecht_dropdown" name="geschlecht" class="dropdown"> <option value="">--Geschlecht auswählen--</option>  <option value= "Männlich">Männlich</option> <option value= "Weiblich">Weiblich</option> <option value= "Divers">Divers</option> </select> </div>
I also tried remove attribute requied in js but it also didnt work I dont know how I can fix it
